# Change duplicate value in a column

Tags: sql, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

Can you please tell me what `SQL query` can I use to change duplicates in one column of my table?
I found these duplicates:

```
SELECT Model, count(*) FROM Devices GROUP BY model HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

I was looking for information on exactly how to change one of the duplicate values, but unfortunately I did not find a specific option for myself, and all the more information is all in abundance filled by deleting the duplicate value line, which I don't need. Not strong in SQL at all. I ask for help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Change what value, to what?

Comment: @jarlh, 
I need to replace the found duplicate with the line `-`. but only with this condition, for example, four models are found in the `Mode`l column:
`Esonic G31CEL2`
`Esonic G31CEL2`
`Esonic G31CEL2`
`Esonic G31CEL2`

at the output you need to get:
`Esonic G31CEL2`
`-`
`-`
`-`

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the command:

```
SELECT Model, count (*) FROM Devices GROUP BY model HAVING count (*)> 1;
```

i get the result:

- 1895 lines = NULL;
- 3383 lines with duplicate values;
- and all these values are 1243.

after applying your command:

```
update Devices set
  Model = '-'
where id not in
  (select
     min(Devices .id)
   from Devices 
   group by Devices.Model)
```

i got 4035 lines changed.
if you count, it turns out, (3383 + 1895) = 5278 - 1243 = 4035
and it seems like everything fits together, the result suits, it works.

Comment: It will create another duplicate contained row if the any group does have more than 2 items.

Comment: @Linker, it's strange why you think so, for a start I looked, what are the duplicates, there are many of them. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use a Window Functions such as `ROW_NUMBER()` with partitioning option in order to group by `Model` column to eliminate the duplicates, and then pick the first rows(`rn=1`) returning from the subquery such as

```
WITH d AS
(
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Model) AS rn
   FROM Devices 
)
SELECT ID, Model -- , and the other columns
  FROM d
 WHERE rn = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a6407257257c883bbbce6616cb180a7f)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

use `exists` as follows:

```
update d 
   set Model = '-'
  from Devices d
where exists (select 1 from device dd where dd.model = d.model and dd.id > d.id)
```

Comment: Your query contains error. Please check it . :)

Comment: I am not able to see any error. Please point out if you find any @Linker.

Comment: Alias name.`update Devices d` creating an error(SQL SERVER 2016). Please check . :)

Comment: @Linker Yes, changed it now. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: @Popeye, I am trying to use your request, but I have an error:


`Execution finished with errors.
Result: near ".": syntax error
At line 1:
update d 
   set d.`

Comment: @alex, Check now

Comment: @Popeye, I tried your request, the database of 50 thousand lines is stuck :)))